# How to calculate customer purchase interval and predict next purchase in python?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, forecasting

Suppose we have a data set consists of columns

> TransactionId, CardNo, TransactionDate

then how can we calculate the customer purchase interval (means if customer A purchased on Jan 1st and after 10 days he again purchased, and then he again purchased after 15 days.) and how to predict the next visit of customer A by analysing the purchasing intervals of customer A.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/buy-til-you-die-predict-customer-lifetime-value-in-python-9701bfd4ddc0) article using Lifetimes that Jonathan suggested, and it is very easy to follow and comprehensive. Take a look

Answer (score 2):

With [Lifetimes](https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/master/Quickstart.html) it's very straight forward to implement.